# "file too short" error for library in CentOS 8

Tags: centos, libraries

I got an error in CentOS 8:

```
eror while loading libraries: /lib64/libgpm.so.2: file too short
```

How can we fix this? I tried to install it several times but, it gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
sudo dnf reinstall gpm-libs
```